# coloring only a Button in Kivy in a RecycleGridLayout

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to develop a program written in python using Kivy for the graphic elements.

```
BoxLayout:
        RecycleView:
            viewclass: 'Button'
            data: [{'text': str(x)} for x in root.data_items]

            RecycleGridLayout:
                cols: 5
                cols_minimum: {0: 400, 1: 180, 2: 62, 3: 62, 4: 62}
                size_hint: 1, None
                default_size: None, dp(35)
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                height: self.minimum_height
```

I used this code to create a grid layout of buttons.
I need a particular Button of the grid to be colored different from the others only if a condition is fulfilled.

The condition is checked in the .py file

```
sql_conn.execute("SELECT ...")
rows = sql_conn.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    for col in row:
        self.data_items.append(col)
    if row[2] == row[4]:
```

As you can see I have a query that fetches all the elements for the grid layout.
The query get some elements from the database and in particular QTA (total quantity) and OK (how many products have been checked).

In the grid layout there will be the name of the products followed by their total and checked quantities.
If the two quantities of the product are the same i want the QTA button to be colored in green.

I tried lot of things but I was able to color only all the buttons of the grid layout.

If I try something like this I will abviously color all the buttons

```
rows = sql_conn.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    for col in row:
        self.data_items.append(col)
    if row[2] == row[4]:
        Button.background_color = [0,255,0,0.3]
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: As you say row is a row of the gridlayout, when you use the `row[2] == row[4]` you are comparing items 3 and 5, my question is: if the above is true, should the entire row change the color?

Comment: if it is not so that item of the row must change the color, since according to your numbering the name has the position 0, then comes the total that would be the position 1 and finally checked quantities that is 2, but you compare the 3 with the 5 `row[2] == row[4]` (remember that the position starts from 0)

Comment: I’m using row[2] == row[4] since there is other stores in the row. Sorry if I didn’t specified that. The check is correct

Comment: Explain better, if `row[2] == row[4]`, which `i` in `row[i]` should the color change?

Comment: Exactly...the color of the button in row[4] should change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RecycleView receives as a data list of dictionaries, in those dictionaries the properties of the elements are indicated, so we must create those properties and then copy it, in your code I see that those dictionaries are creating them in the .kv, now you must do it in the .py as I show below:

***.py**

```
rows = sql_conn.fetchall()
values = []
for row in rows:
    change_color = row[2] == row[4]
    for i, col in enumerate(row):
        text = str(col)
        color =  [0, 255, 0, 0.3] if i == 4 and change_color else [1, 1, 1, 1]
        d = dict(text=text, background_color=color)
        values.append(d)

self.data_items = values
```

***.kv**

```
BoxLayout:
    RecycleView:
        viewclass: 'Button'
        data: root.data_items # <----

        RecycleGridLayout:
            cols: 5
            cols_minimum: {0: 400, 1: 180, 2: 62, 3: 62, 4: 62}
            size_hint: 1, None
            default_size: None, dp(35)
            default_size_hint: 1, None
            height: self.minimum_height
```